# How to remove duplicate object values from the array which is nested inside the object of an array?

Tags: javascript

I have array structure as shown in below

```js
[
  {
    "id": "cbdfc96a-c788-45cd-bdd1-7d573cc8c474",
    "refId": "1",
    "reference": "<p>1646 Journal of Investigative Dermatology ( 2017 ) , Volume 137</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 1</p>",
        "id": "e9c207ae-3d08-4eb2-94d1-b6ae713862d3"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 1</p>",
        "id": "e1486639-aa46-4513-992b-17d8d66f06c8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "90b187ab-26ef-45c0-a6a0-bf7dcfde660f",
    "refId": "2",
    "reference": "<p>ZK Jabbar - Lopez et al . Evaluation of Biologic Therapy Options for Psoriasis</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2</p>",
        "id": "fc430895-912a-4e4b-884c-f08600e06ec8"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2 3</p>",
        "id": "a1296b1f-530e-4e1b-b2d0-f97bba192a1a"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2 3</p>",
        "id": "090737d5-48ac-4e3f-973d-9e1de206252b"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2</p>",
        "id": "6d5f89be-305e-4751-a7ca-75d9b0f2057e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "e8c3a958-7fa4-40e1-a83a-44c85ebb05a7",
    "refId": "3",
    "reference": "<p>Table 2. Relative treatment rankings ( outcomes at 12 to 16 wk )</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 3</p>",
        "id": "f9082af8-3c2f-477b-b113-a96f320415d1"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 3</p>",
        "id": "2d7e65b8-e516-40bf-8957-c0fb4b819aa9"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Expected result is

```js
[
  {
    "id": "cbdfc96a-c788-45cd-bdd1-7d573cc8c474",
    "refId": "1",
    "reference": "<p>1646 Journal of Investigative Dermatology ( 2017 ) , Volume 137</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 1</p>",
        "id": "e9c207ae-3d08-4eb2-94d1-b6ae713862d3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "90b187ab-26ef-45c0-a6a0-bf7dcfde660f",
    "refId": "2",
    "reference": "<p>ZK Jabbar - Lopez et al . Evaluation of Biologic Therapy Options for Psoriasis</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2</p>",
        "id": "fc430895-912a-4e4b-884c-f08600e06ec8"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2 3</p>",
        "id": "a1296b1f-530e-4e1b-b2d0-f97bba192a1a"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "e8c3a958-7fa4-40e1-a83a-44c85ebb05a7",
    "refId": "3",
    "reference": "<p>Table 2. Relative treatment rankings ( outcomes at 12 to 16 wk )</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 3</p>",
        "id": "f9082af8-3c2f-477b-b113-a96f320415d1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried this solution but didnot get the expected result.

```js
const finalListmergedArray = [
  {
    "id": "cbdfc96a-c788-45cd-bdd1-7d573cc8c474",
    "refId": "1",
    "reference": "<p>1646 Journal of Investigative Dermatology ( 2017 ) , Volume 137</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 1</p>",
        "id": "e9c207ae-3d08-4eb2-94d1-b6ae713862d3"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 1</p>",
        "id": "e1486639-aa46-4513-992b-17d8d66f06c8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "90b187ab-26ef-45c0-a6a0-bf7dcfde660f",
    "refId": "2",
    "reference": "<p>ZK Jabbar - Lopez et al . Evaluation of Biologic Therapy Options for Psoriasis</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2</p>",
        "id": "fc430895-912a-4e4b-884c-f08600e06ec8"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2 3</p>",
        "id": "a1296b1f-530e-4e1b-b2d0-f97bba192a1a"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2 3</p>",
        "id": "090737d5-48ac-4e3f-973d-9e1de206252b"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2</p>",
        "id": "6d5f89be-305e-4751-a7ca-75d9b0f2057e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "e8c3a958-7fa4-40e1-a83a-44c85ebb05a7",
    "refId": "3",
    "reference": "<p>Table 2. Relative treatment rankings ( outcomes at 12 to 16 wk )</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 3</p>",
        "id": "f9082af8-3c2f-477b-b113-a96f320415d1"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 3</p>",
        "id": "2d7e65b8-e516-40bf-8957-c0fb4b819aa9"
      }
    ]
  }
]
    // Loop through array values
    for (let i = 0; i < finalListmergedArray.length; i++) {
      for (
        let j = 0;
        j < finalListmergedArray[i]["list"].length;
        j++
      ) {
        var result = [
          ...new Map(
            finalListmergedArray[i]["list"].map((o) => [
              JSON.stringify(o),
              o,
            ])
          ).values(),
        ];
        finalListmergedArray[i]["list"] = result;
      }
    }
    console.log(finalListmergedArray)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to remove `text` duplicates values from `list` attribute. To be clear, those objects are actually unique because each one has an unique id.

An approach to solve this is to create a `Map` to store unique text values for each object. Then you filter your `list`, validate if `text` is included at your `Map`. If it's included you return false, otherwise you add `text` to your `Map` and return true:

```
// data here is your array
const filteredData = data.map(item => {
  const includedText = new Map()
  const list = item.list.filter(content => {
    if (includedText.has(content.text)) return false
    includedText.set(content.text)
    return true
  })

  return { ...item, list }
})

console.log(filteredData)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to merge with text in the list, you can use a list to store the processed elements. Below is the code snipped for the same.

```
const input = [
  {
    "id": "cbdfc96a-c788-45cd-bdd1-7d573cc8c474",
    "refId": "1",
    "reference": "<p>1646 Journal of Investigative Dermatology ( 2017 ) , Volume 137</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 1</p>",
        "id": "e9c207ae-3d08-4eb2-94d1-b6ae713862d3"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 1</p>",
        "id": "e1486639-aa46-4513-992b-17d8d66f06c8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "90b187ab-26ef-45c0-a6a0-bf7dcfde660f",
    "refId": "2",
    "reference": "<p>ZK Jabbar - Lopez et al . Evaluation of Biologic Therapy Options for Psoriasis</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2</p>",
        "id": "fc430895-912a-4e4b-884c-f08600e06ec8"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2 3</p>",
        "id": "a1296b1f-530e-4e1b-b2d0-f97bba192a1a"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2 3</p>",
        "id": "090737d5-48ac-4e3f-973d-9e1de206252b"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 2</p>",
        "id": "6d5f89be-305e-4751-a7ca-75d9b0f2057e"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "e8c3a958-7fa4-40e1-a83a-44c85ebb05a7",
    "refId": "3",
    "reference": "<p>Table 2. Relative treatment rankings ( outcomes at 12 to 16 wk )</p>",
    "list": [
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 3</p>",
        "id": "f9082af8-3c2f-477b-b113-a96f320415d1"
      },
      {
        "text": "<p>Annot 3</p>",
        "id": "2d7e65b8-e516-40bf-8957-c0fb4b819aa9"
      }
    ]
  }
]
//Solution....
input.forEach(function(i) {
    let processed = [];
    const newList = [];
    i.list.forEach(function(l) {
      if( processed.indexOf(l.text) < 0 ) { //id not in list
        newList.push(l);
        processed.push(l.text);
      }
    });
    i.list = newList;
});


console.log(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve with [Rambda](https://ramdajs.com/):

```
const expected = R.map(({list, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  list: R.uniqWith(R.eqProps('text'))(list)
}))(input)
```

See sandbox for your reference: https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.27.0#?const%20input%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22cbdfc96a-c788-45cd-bdd1-7d573cc8c474%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22refId%22%3A%20%221%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22reference%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3E1646%20Journal%20of%20Investigative%20Dermatology%20%28%202017%20%29%20%2C%20Volume%20137%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22list%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3EAnnot%201%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22e9c207ae-3d08-4eb2-94d1-b6ae713862d3%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3EAnnot%201%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22e1486639-aa46-4513-992b-17d8d66f06c8%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%2290b187ab-26ef-45c0-a6a0-bf7dcfde660f%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22refId%22%3A%20%222%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22reference%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3EZK%20Jabbar%20-%20Lopez%20et%20al%20.%20Evaluation%20of%20Biologic%20Therapy%20Options%20for%20Psoriasis%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22list%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3EAnnot%202%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22fc430895-912a-4e4b-884c-f08600e06ec8%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3EAnnot%202%203%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22a1296b1f-530e-4e1b-b2d0-f97bba192a1a%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3EAnnot%202%203%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22090737d5-48ac-4e3f-973d-9e1de206252b%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3EAnnot%202%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%226d5f89be-305e-4751-a7ca-75d9b0f2057e%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22e8c3a958-7fa4-40e1-a83a-44c85ebb05a7%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22refId%22%3A%20%223%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22reference%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3ETable%202.%20Relative%20treatment%20rankings%20%28%20outcomes%20at%2012%20to%2016%20wk%20%29%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22list%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3EAnnot%203%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%22f9082af8-3c2f-477b-b113-a96f320415d1%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22text%22%3A%20%22%3Cp%3EAnnot%203%3C%2Fp%3E%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22id%22%3A%20%222d7e65b8-e516-40bf-8957-c0fb4b819aa9%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20expected%20%3D%20R.map%28%28%20%7Blist%2C%20...rest%7D%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%20...rest%2C%0A%20%20%20%20list%3A%20R.uniqWith%28R.eqProps%28%27text%27%29%29%28list%29%0A%7D%29%29%28input%29%0A%0Aexpected%20%2F%2F%0A%0A

Comment: Cant we achieve this without any npm packege?.